# Appending to file through FtpCommand C++

Tags: c++, ftp, wininet

I'm trying to append information to `mainfile.txt` that is located on ftp server. After looking through documentation, it appears since `wininet.h` doesn't have any methods to append that `FtpCommand()` will need to fascilitate appending through a command; the problem that I am having is that I believe that I'm messing up on the command due to hardly no documentation on it. If anyone with any experience doing this can shine some light on it or point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
HINTERNET hInternet;
HINTERNET hFtpSession;

hInternet = InternetOpen(NULL, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);
hFtpSession = InternetConnect(hInternet, L"host", INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT, L"username", 
                              L"password", INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE, 0);

if (FtpCommand(hFtpSession, FALSE, FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_ASCII, 
               L"APPE C:\\Users\\Brandon\\Desktop\\test.txt mainfile.txt", 0, 0))
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Sucess", L"Window", NULL);

else {  
    PrintServerResponse();
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed", L"Window", NULL);
}

InternetCloseHandle(hFtpSession);
InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);
```

When I send the command `APPE C:\\Users\\Brandon\\Desktop\\test.txt mainfile.txt` my response is...

```
Response error code: 0
Response message:
```

When I send the command `APPEND C:\\Users\\Brandon\\Desktop\\test.txt mainfile.txt` my response is...

```
Response error code: 0
Response message: 500 APPEND not understood
```

I believe that `error code: 0` refers to invalid syntax, but am not sure. The second command helps to show that I am correctly connected to the server.

Originally my code uses `FtpPutFile(hFtpSession, L"C:\\Users\\Brandon\\Desktop\\test.txt", L"mainfile.txt", FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0)` to place the file to the server, but doesn't take use of `FtpCommand()`

**EDIT:** It would also appear that the `APPE C:\\Users\\Brandon\\Desktop\\test.txt mainfile.txt` command that I'm sending is "working"; While it's not actually transfering my local file it's creating empty documents on the server listed as `C:\Users\Brandon\Desktop\test.txt mainfile.txt`. Now I definitely believe that my error is coming from the use of the `APPE` command.

Comment: Your `APPE` command is malformed. Read the FTP specification, [RFC 959](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc959).

Comment: Is it still malformed in my answer to the problem? I got it to correctly append, but not sure if there's something I can do better.

Comment: The format of the `APPE` command is fine now, but you are not checking the response for error before calling `InternetWriteFile()`. Also, `InternetWriteFile()` can write fewer bytes than requested, so it should be in a loop that pays attention to the return values of the write to know what data still needs to be written and when to stop looping. Also, don't forget to close the `res` handle after the transfer is finished.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to crudely construct it last night without error checking. Will the validity of the APPE command dictate if there is a server timeout? That's the only serious error in my application right now.

Answer (score 0):

So, `APPE` specifies the *remote-file* and has nothing to do with the transfer of the *local-file*. Once the `APPE` command has been used the `FtpCommand` will write the response to the variable and then you need to use `InternetWriteFile` to copy the contents of the *local-file* over. My only problem now is the formatting it's giving me, but it's much more workable now.

Code:

```
    HINTERNET res;
    DWORD d; //make sure all bits written
    CHAR * texttowrite = "test write";

    FtpCommand(hFtpSession, TRUE, FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 
               L"APPE mainfile.txt", 0, &res); //specifices where to write to
    InternetWriteFile(res, texttowrite, 
                      strlen(texttowrite), &d); //writes text to ftp response
```